# jQuery - cycle through classes

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of text fields. User hits a button and they are all checked. Some will have errors. I am trying to develop a little "ERROR" link, and I want it to cycle through the text fields that have errors. The list is long so it's going to have to scroll the window to the error. Then, when the user hits the button again, scroll to the next one.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$('#scroll_errors').click(function() {
    $(window).next().scrollTop($('.error_class').position().top); 
    return false;
});
```

It's not working. If I do this:

```
$('#scroll_errors').click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($('.error_class').position().top); 
    return false;
});
```

I can get it to go to the first error, but that is it. Clicking on subsequent times does nothing.

Is there a simple way to do this? Usually there is in jQuery!

Comment: have you looked at jquery validate?

Comment: might consider hiding parts that are ok and let user see all the errors in one place

Comment: validate won't work. And having all the errors in one place would make it a lot less user friendly. My thinking now is putting the id's of the error fields in an array and then somehow stepping through that with jquery. I need some help though!